# How to auto update excel linked data?

Tags: python, excel, vba, automation

I have a source excel file(source) linked to a folder of files(templates), and all the templates are eventually linked to the output file(output). So if there are number updated in the source file, I need to open the templates one by one and refresh each template, and then refresh the output file to reflect the updates in all the template files. I am wondering if there's a way to make this process more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you already automating the opening and updating and asking how to speed it up or are you asking how it can be automated?

Comment: I am asking how to automate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a specific answer, but I can give you some tips that may hopefully allow you to create the program that you're looking for.

To open a workbook in VBA you want to use [Application.Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open). To use that method, you need to know the exact file name and location. If you have a lot of files, you may want to define directories instead of individual file paths. That would be done like so:

```
Dim Directory as Object

Set Directory = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").getfolder(DirectoryPath)
'DirectoryPath is the folder location written like "C:\Users\Guy\Documents\My Received Files\"
```

You can then loop through the files in the folder like so:

```
Dim oFile As Variant

For Each oFile In Directory.Files
    'Example of how to open them
    If oFile.Name Like "*.xls?" Then Application.Workbooks.Open oFile.Path
Next oFile
```

When you do Application.Workbooks.Open you can also save that workbook as a reference so that you can update the data inside it. You would do it like so:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
'FilePath is the specific location of the File
```

Once you have the workbook, you can reference whichever cells you want using references like .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") .

To put everything I've discussed above into one example:

```
Sub Open_and_Edit()

    Dim Directory As Object, oFile As Variant, wb As Workbook, DirectoryPath As String

    'For this example, I'll use my desktop as the Directory
    DirectoryPath = "C:\Users\Michel\Desktop\"

    Set Directory = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").getfolder(DirectoryPath)

    For Each oFile In Directory.Files
        'Opening every excel file on my desktop
        If oFile.Name Like "*.xls?" Then
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
            
            'opening and closing a dozen workbooks can cause annoying screen jittering, my prefered fix:
            wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
            
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Hello World!"
            
            wb.Close savechanges:=True
        End If
    Next oFile

End Sub
```